# Why does the path parameter for Bitmap throw "ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid" on Ubuntu Server 20.04?

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, discord.net

I've decided to let my Discord bot run on my new Ubuntu 20.04 home server.

The bot does run on the server, however I get the following error when I am trying to create a `Bitmap` from a path:

```
System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
   at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.CheckStatus(Int32 status)
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(String filename, Boolean useIcm)
   at Aurelia.ImageProcessor.ImageBuilder(String filename, String idolname, String group, String rarity, Int32 rar, String id, String pathDefiner) in /home/aurelia/discordBots/Aurelia/AureliaBot/Aurelia/ImageProcessor.cs:line 21
```

If I debug it in VS on my home Windows PC, I don't get this error and it works fine.

I've checked every parameter & every parameter should be fine.

```
Bitmap cardTemp = new Bitmap($"assets\\groups\\{group}\\{idolname}\\{filename}");
Bitmap card = new Bitmap(cardTemp, 800, 1200);
Bitmap rareFrameTemp = new Bitmap($"assets\\frames\\{rarity}Frame.png");
```

Only the first line throws the error, and yes the file exists.
Thank you!

Comment: Use / in place of \ in path

Comment: Thanks! Now it works just fine!

Comment: glad to hear that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your paths, while they work for Windows, will not work for Unix based systems as they use forward slashes - `/` - not backward slashes `\` as a directory separator character.

Use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-5.0) for a cross-platform solution.

It will use the [`Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar?view=net-5.0) which will provide a platform-specific character:

```
var cardTempPath = Path.Combine("assets", "groups", group, idolname, filename);
var rareFrameTemp = Path.Combine("assets", "frames", $"{rarity}Frame.png");

Bitmap cardTemp = new Bitmap(cardTempPath);
Bitmap card = new Bitmap(cardTemp, 800, 1200);
Bitmap rareFrameTemp = new Bitmap(rareFrameTemp);
```